# jQuery stop current domain URL in load

Tags: jquery, html

I'm storing the urls from links inside each element on the page and inserting a new div in each of those elements to target:

```js
$('.element a').each(function(){
    var storePLU = $(this).attr('href');
    $('<div class="newDivs"></div>').insertBefore(this);
});
```

Then I'm loading an element that exists on a different page (of the same domain) which works fine if I manually specify the page url:

```js
$('.newDivs').load('/product/productName/  + #targetDivOnOtherPage'); 
/* 
This returns the correct elements from:
https://example.com/product/productName/stock 
*/
```

However if I try to populate the url part of the load with the url's stored in the storePLU variable:

```js
$('.newDivs').load("'" + storePLU + " " + "#targetDivOnOtherPage'");
/* 
This returns an error as even though the variable storePLU would return:
/product/productName/ which is correct
However when used in this .load() it tries to load:
https://example.com/category'https://example.com/product/productName/ 
*/
```

I want it to not prefix the current url to the beginning of the intended url. I think the issue is that it's expecting to see an apostrophe and the intended url at the beginning, however it starts with Quotation marks so it just adds the current url in place as default first.

How can I get this working?

Current complete code:

```js
$('.element a').each(function(){
    var storePLU = $(this).attr('href');
    $('<div class="newDivs"></div>').insertBefore(this);
    $('.newDivs').load("'" + storePLU + " " + "#targetDivOnOtherPage'");
});
```

Comment: Remove the nonsense `'` that you inserted there for no good reason …

Comment: Just do `load(storePLU  + ' #targetDivOnOtherPage')`. Also note you will load all divs of that class with same content

Comment: Thanks it was that simple, strangely I was taught that it needed the ' and it even works as mentioned with the apostrophe's if you manually add the url it works. Which made me believe they were needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using all sorts of unnecessary quotes. All you are wanting to do is simple string concatenation so that the final string passed to `load()` is a valid url and selector after a space

Try

```
$('.newDivs').load(storePLU + " #targetDivOnOtherPage");
```